# amsart + \makeatletter + @ @ @ in a caption = disappear

Tags: captions, amsart, catcodes

In some circumstance adding `@` into the caption will cause it to disappear.
This can be solved by adding `\makeatother` at proper places.
I just want to know why is this happening.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Can you see the caption of Fig.~\ref{fig:one}?

\begin{figure}
  \caption{%
    You can see this caption if \texttt{hyperref} is in. @
  }
  \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

Can you see the caption of Fig.~\ref{fig:two}?

\begin{figure}
  \caption{%
    You cannot see this caption if \texttt{\string\makeatletter}is on @ @ @
  }
  \label{fig:two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Changing to non-AMS documentclasses the problem disappears.

Comment: amsmart uses @@ (with catcode letter) as marker in internal commands, and so some test fails if the argument has them too.

Comment: There is no reason to turn `\makeatletter` on in a document without turning it off before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I use `pgfutil` quite often so I usually have `\makeatletter` on for my entire document. But yeah, (perhaps) this is a bad habit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That would explain. Feel free to close the question if you don't want to make it an answer.

Comment: @Symbol1 It's definitely a bad habit. If you need `@`-commands in the body of the document, define aliases for them with no `@`.

Comment: OK I will......